# Text Rollover Effect without Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a phone number link at the top of my website, the number is 1300 GO POOPIES. (for example purposes :P)

```
<h1 class="phone-text">
<a href="tel:+6113007667437">1300 GO POOPIES</a>
</h1>
```

So basically, when a person puts their mouse over the 1300 GO POOPIES it changes to 1300 46 7667437.

I don't want to use an image however as I want to preserve the click-to-call functionality.

I tried to do something with CSS, with minimal success however.

```
.phone-text::after {
  content: "1300 GO POOPIES";
}

.phone-text:hover:after {
  content: "1300 76 67437";
}
```

not sure if this is out of the boundaries of css, and needs java...

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to load jQuery or JS.
CSS+HTML only.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/TZVnE/1/)

Comment: Better.  JQuery seemed like overkill and I didn't like having content in the style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a reason for you avoiding JavaScript, then this can be achieved with just CSS if you're willing to add some extra markup.  You do so by putting two elements inside the `<a>` tag, one with the numeric number, one with the alphanumeric number.  Then you can hide/show them independently with `a:hover` selectors.

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="phone-text">
  <a href="tel:+6113007667437">
    <span class="letters">1300 GO POOPIES</span>
    <span class="digits">1300 76 67437</span>
  </a>
</h1>​
```

**CSS**

```
.phone-text a .digits,
.phone-text a:hover .letters {
  display: none;
}

.phone-text a .letters,
.phone-text a:hover .digits {
  display: inline;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xuFdA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You want something a little more in depth... Here goes.

Html

```
<a href="tel:+6113007667437">
  <div id="hide">
    <h1>1300 76 67437</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>1300 GO POOPIES</h1>
  </div>
</a>
```

And your css

```
div{
 position:absolute;
 background:#ffffff;
}
div#hide:hover{
 display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).text('1300 76 67437')
  },
  function(){
    $(this).text('1300 GO POOPIES')
  }
});
```

Comment: @Ace Stooge to be more specific you may change `a` with your class name `phone-text` or add an id

Comment: the advantage of using **jQuery instead of CSS** is that usually works with all browsers.

Comment: @ChrisGP - which browsers exactly does CSS not work in that jQuery does? I assume you're talking about IE, but even IE6 will happily support CSS hover, maybe not in the way that the OP was doing it, but it's certainly not a problematic question to answer in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

How about this http://jsfiddle.net/tzerb/S52bz/
    < a class="phone-text" href="tel:+6113007667437" >< /a >

Answer (score 0):

here you have a variation to the solution proposed by **yaponyal**. it works without the `>` sign.

```
.hiden {
display:none;
}
a:hover .shown {
display:none;
}
a:hover .hiden {
display:inline;
}
```

​

Comment: Of ourse It is ;) I simply choose the elements in <a> tag.